# Using c# property DHCPLeaseLifetime

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was looking for a way to find out and use how much lifetime is left in a dhcp lease and MS has documentation here, but I guess I am really just not sure how to use this property. I haven't been able to find much.

Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.unicastipaddressinformation.dhcpleaselifetime.aspx)

Comment: Documentation says it returns the number of seconds left...what else do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider [the MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.unicastaddresses.aspx).
It illustrates how you get to the lease lifetime.

The (condensed) version of the example for future reference:

> ```
>     For Each adapter In Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
>         For Each uni In adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
>             Console.WriteLine("  Unicast Address ......................... : {0}", uni.Address)
>             Console.WriteLine("  DHCP Leased Life Time ................ : {0}", uni.DhcpLeaseLifetime)
>         Next uni
>     Next adapter
> ```

Comment: This looks like it could be exactly what I needed, I'll take a look now.